# type mismatch 13 in excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba, types, type-mismatch

The following code worked perfectly under excel 2003, but in 2010 returns error 'type mismatch 13' in the following line "If Array2(1, i) <> 0 Then"

Anyone has any ideas how to solve this ?

Thx in advance

Sonny

Her is the code:

```
Sub BerekenGepresteerdeUrenVoorEenMaand(SheetNaam As String)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim Array1 As Variant
Dim Array2 As Variant

Dim Range1 As Range
Dim Range2 As Range
Dim RangeTarget1 As Range
Dim RangeTarget2 As Range
Dim mRange As Excel.Range
Dim RangeNieuwSaldo As Range

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim l As Integer

Dim subTotaal As Double

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetNaam).Activate

Set Range1 = ActiveSheet.Range("EersteRij")
Set Range2 = ActiveSheet.Range("LaatsteRij")
Set RangeTarget1 = ActiveSheet.Range("NaamVeld")
Set RangeTarget2 = ActiveSheet.Range("SaldiVeld")

Array1 = Range1.Value
Array2 = Range2.Value

RangeTarget1.Locked = False
RangeTarget2.Locked = False

j = 0
For i = LBound(Array1, 2) To UBound(Array1, 2)

If Array2(1, i) <> 0 Then 'Line generating error

j = j + 1

RangeTarget1.Cells(j, 1).Value = Array1(1, i)
RangeTarget2.Cells(j, 1).Value = Array2(1, i)

Else

End If

Next

For k = j + 1 To 11

RangeTarget1.Cells(k, 1).Value = ""
RangeTarget2.Cells(k, 1).Value = ""

Next

RangeTarget1.Locked = False
RangeTarget2.Locked = False

Erase Array1
Erase Array2

Set Range1 = Nothing
Set Range2 = Nothing
Set RangeTarget1 = Nothing
Set RangeTarget2 = Nothing

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub
```

Comment: change `Dim i As Interger` to `Dim i As Integer`

Comment: Sorry this was a mistype when copying the code to the forum

Comment: Array2 = Range2.Value , make sure Range2 is something @user3220149

Comment: @user3220149 And I think its `Array2(i,1)` not ?

Answer (score 0):

i think , at some time , i gets bigger than the input data in array2...
like no data stored in array2(1,10000) or so, and nothing is not a number (like <>0)
so maybe u need a fail-proof condition before your faulty line like:

```
if not array2(1,i) is nothing then 'or you might just want to exit the For loop here.
    if array2(1,i)<>0 then ...
'if this doesn't work try if not IsEmpty(array2(1,i)) as condition
```

try it, i can't tell more without seing the actual data here...

read more about ubound maybe too, its the upper limit of your array, being data in it or not.
I once thought too that it is the last entry of data in my array, but no, in fact.

```
 dim test(20) as integer
 test(1)=23
 ..
 test(10)=44 'last input
 a=ubound(test) 'my guess it will return 20, and not 10
```

Comment: OK Thanx for the reply.
I found out there was a problem withe the data in Array2: it contained some error values which generated the type mismatch error.

Problem solved !